# compact and self adjoint square root of an operator

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let H a Hilbert space and $T:H\rightarrow H$ a linear bounded, self-adjoint, positive and compact operator. How can i prove that the square root of T, $\ T^{1/2}:H\rightarrow H$ is also compact and self-adjoint;
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the diagonalization of compact self-adjoint operators makes this easy. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

- As $ T $ is a self-adjoint operator, we can apply the Continuous Functional Calculus (C.F.C.) to $ T $.
- As $ T $ is a positive operator, i.e., $ {\sigma_{B(\mathcal{H})}}(T) \subseteq [0,\infty) $, we can apply the $ \sqrt{\bullet} $-function to $ T $ to obtain $ \sqrt{T} $.
- The range of the C.F.C. of $ T $ is the $ \| \cdot \|_{B(\mathcal{H})} $-closed $ ^{\ast} $-subalgebra of $ B(\mathcal{H}) $ generated by $ T $.
- As involution is a continuous operation on $ B(\mathcal{H}) $, it follows that $ \sqrt{T} $ is a self-adjoint operator.
- As $ T \in K(\mathcal{H}) $ and $ K(\mathcal{H}) $ is a $ \| \cdot \|_{B(\mathcal{H})} $-closed ideal of $ B(\mathcal{H}) $, it follows that the range of the C.F.C. of $ T $ is contained in $ K(\mathcal{H}) $.
- Therefore, $ \sqrt{T} \in K(\mathcal{H}) $.

Comment: i was looking for an answer whithout using $C^*-$algebra tools. the compactness can be derived from spectral representation but what about self-adjointness;

Comment: The range of C.F.C is not in the ideal of compacts. Take 1+T for example.

Comment: What about uniqueness?