# compact positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

let‎ ‎$ T \in K ( H ) $ ‎be‎ ‎$ T ‎\geqslant ‎0‎ $‎.‎
‎

What is the best way to show the following statement?

> There is a compact, positive and unique operator ‎$ A$‎ so that ‎$ A‎^{2} =‎‎ ‎T‎ $.‎

( K ( H ) defined compact operator)

‎

Comment: There are different definitions of what $T\geq 0$ should mean. I am assuming that it implies self-adjointness in the definition you use?

Comment: What have you tired? You can get a positive square root from the functional calculus very easily.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148162/square-root-of-compact-operator http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311310/compact-and-self-adjoint-square-root-of-an-operator http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706525/positive-compact-operator-has-unique-square-root http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111827/square-root-of-compact-positive-operator